# How to prevent sending email to invalid email addresses in SES

Tags: node.js, email, amazon-ses

With AWS SES sdk (production) we can send email to any email addresses and get a `MessageId` in response. However, if the email address was invalid for example `sifatul@blah.blah` SES would send an email to the sender email titled:

> Delivery Status Notification (Failure)

which mostly lands in spam folder.

**How to avoid sending email to such kinds of invalid email addresses?**

FYI, DDOS attack with many invalid email address might make AWS suspend SES service under that AWS account.

Comment: You can lookup if blah.blah has a valid MX and possibly a TXT SPF record

Comment: @Matt this wont help as some case the domain is valid but prefix might be invalid. Forexample, blah@google.com is invalid